# connection of tanks with multiple fluids

Tags: anylogic

I have 6 different fluid inlets (Fluidenter) and I want to connect them to 12 possible tanks. I want to make it so that each of these fluids can connect to all tanks (i.e., the fluids can be directed to each of the 12 tanks), but I want to ensure that the fluids do not mix in the tanks (i.e., if one fluid enters that tank first, only other liquid of the same type can enter)

I defined the types of fluids according to specific batches. I thought about joining SelectInputs to connect the 6 FluidEnter to the tanks, but this approach would not be advantageous, as I would have to connect them to each tank together with SelectOutputs to select the batches.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to make this connection. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help